# Elasticsearch search query on hot and warm nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

With hot/warm architecture in Elasticsearch, is a search query on several indices, with index pattern or alias, on nodes both hot and warm more efficient than with a simple architecture ?

I mean is the warm nodes a limiting factor in the query or does the hot nodes improve performance anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of a hot/warm architecture is to:

- be able to index current data in an optimal way on hot nodes
- while still be able to rapidly search recent data on hot nodes
- and yet also be able to search older data on warm nodes or even (c)older data on cold nodes.

As time goes by, older indexes are moved from hot (fast) nodes to warm (slower) nodes to (even slower) cold nodes.

However, if your search alias spans all indexes (located on warm and hot nodes alike) then the query performance can be as bad as your slowest warm node. Ideally, you should have at least two search aliases:

- One for recent data (e.g. `search_recent`) that spans only the indexes on hot nodes
- Another one for all data (e.g. `search_all`) that spans all indexes.

That way, most of your searches on recent data (i.e. on `search_recent`) would only hit hot nodes, but if you want to search on older data you can do so too (i.e. on `search_all`).

In the former case, you can expect that the query goes fast (since only run on hot nodes) and in the latter case, you know in advance that the query will be slower (since executing on warm/cold nodes).

Comment: How I can set alias depend on index phase (hot, warm, cold)? @Val

Comment: @YuriyBosov I'd suggest you ask a new question with your use case, it'll be easier to answer

Comment: all done: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721671/elasticsearch-ilm-setting-aliases-depends-on-phase-hot-warm-cold)

Answer (score 1):

Hot-warm architecture is preferred for time series data (e.g. logging). Any query that searches the latest data is going to hit hot nodes and be fast. Warm nodes are designed to handle a large amount of read-only indices that are not as likely to be queried frequently.

If your query is going to hit both, warm and hot nodes, then the overall query performance is going to depend on performance of the slowest nodes. In this case that is performance of warm nodes. Having really fast hot nodes will not improve the query performance in this case.