# Elasticsearch ILM: setting aliases depends on phase (hot, warm, cold)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have working Hot-Warm-Cold architecture with Index Lifecycle Management. I need search using only hot or warm nodes.
A logical solution for this - using different aliases for hot/warm/cold indices, but I can't find how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to do this using ILM actions.

However, there are some [works in progress](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/47881) in that area and you can definitely +1 that issue.

Comment: Maybe you know any external solution?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I will check and report here if I find any